# Evaluate Line integral with Green's Theorem

Tags: vector-analysis, line-integrals, greens-theorem

Calculate
$$\displaystyle\oint_C(x\sin(e^y)+xy)dx+(\frac{x^2}{2}e^y\cos(e^y)+x^2y^3)dy$$
where $C$ is the polygon with vertices $(-1,0), (0,1), (1,1), (2,0), (0,-2) $ oriented counter clockwise.

---

I got $\displaystyle \int_{x=-1}^{x=1}\int_{y=x-2}^{y=1} (2xy^3-x)dydx$

Should I continue or am I wrong?

Comment: It should be $\iint_D (2xy^3-x)dydx$ over where $\partial D=C$ but the limits of your integral seem to be wrong. Have you the final result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach and application of Green's theorem is correct. However limits of integral is not correct. Please see shaded region in the diagram.

[image]

Integrating wrt $dx$ first will require two integrals.

For $ - 2 \leq y \leq 0$, $x$ is bound between lines $x = - \frac{y+2}{2}$ and $x = y + 2$.

For $0 \leq y \leq 1$, $x$ is bound between lines $x = y-1$ and $x = 2-y$.

So the integral should be,

$ \displaystyle \int_{-2}^0 \int_{-(y+2)/2}^{y+2} (2 xy^3 -x) ~ dx ~ dy ~ + $

$ \displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_{y-1}^{2-y} (2 xy^3 -x) ~ dx ~ dy $

Comment: Yes, I agree! I got $-49/20$.

Comment: @RobertZ yes I get the same.

Comment: An incestuous question/answer pair :) Just a space between you!

Comment: @TedShifrin thankfully a space exists :)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, it helped a lot!